# how to display the two different columns from the selected year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, combobox

I do not know how will I display the position and names of the officers from year selected by the user.

Edit:

I used ajax now, but I'm still having a problem. When I click the combobox and select a year, the officers still don't show up. Only the table with the header Position and Name that shows up, but no data from my database under those columns.

**getyear.php**

```
<?php
$q = strval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','test');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM officers WHERE year = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Position</th>
<th>Name</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['position'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**main.php**

```
<form>
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM officers ORDER BY year DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* assign an onchange event handler */
    echo "<select name='year' onchange='showofficers(this.value)'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<option value='" . $row['year'] ."'>" . $row['year'];
    }   
    echo "</select> <br>";
    ?>
    <div id="txtHint">
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    /* event handler ~ no ajax function shown */
    function showofficers(str){
        if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getyear.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you want to show the position and names in select box? also what are the fields name for `position and names` in your table?

Comment: No, I want the year to show in select box. And when a year is selected, the set of officers will display in a table with the position and name. My fiels name for position and name is as is. `position` and `name` . And also `year` is my another field in my table. @Anant

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? When the user selects a year from drop down another query is run to get the officers promoted in that year?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want to achieve! I'm sorry I suck at explaining, but i'm glad u got my point. @awinwood

Comment: This could be achieved in 2 ways. First the select will submit a form from an onchange event. The form posts the year back to the same page and if the post value is set you run the query for officers details with the year in the where clause. Second is to use javascript to send an ajax request to another page for the data from the onchange event. The ajax request is the better way to go so you're not reloading the entire page each time but is slightly more complicated to understand. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Thank you mister. I'll try to do this and will update my question whenever I have this working. Thank u for explaining it to me @awinwood

Comment: Hi sir @awinwood I have used ajax and edited my question. I hope you can help me out again. Thank you :)

Comment: Had it right already. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

some pseudo-code o give you an idea of how you could achieve the desired goal.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT year FROM officers ORDER BY year DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* assign an onchange event handler */
    echo "<select name='year' onchange='showofficers(this.value)'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<option value='" . $row['year'] ."'>" . $row['year'];
    }   
    echo "</select> <br>";

?>


<script>
    /* event handler ~ no ajax function shown */
    function showofficers( value ){
        /* 
            use ajax to send a request that fetches the officers details
            based upon the year selected. Preferred method=POST for ajax query
        */
        alert( 'send '+value+' via ajax, build the sql query and use the ajax callback to generate the new html content' );
    }
</script>


<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        /* Intercept and process ajax request */

        /* the year is POSTed by ajax */
        $year = $_POST['year'];

        $sql='select * from table where year='.$year;

        $res=$db->query( $sql );

        if( $res ){
            /* process recordset and send back response */
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll try to make this work using ajax as what you both have said. Will update u when i have this working already. ty :)

Comment: Hi mister, i did use ajax just like what u told me, but i'm still having a problem. I have edited my question with the current problem i have. thank you for helping :) @RamRaider

Comment: what is happening or not happening? Is the request getting sent ok? Is it querying the db ok?

Comment: It is working now, I updated my question with the correct code. :D Thank you so much! People here are the best! :D

Comment: As you're using a get request start by calling that page directly in the browser with a known value in the query string. Once you have that returning the expected response work on the ajax request itself until that works.